# How can I delete uv layers with python?

Tags: python, uv

I'm using this code the access the uv maps array:

```
import bpy  

selection_ = bpy.context.selected_objects

for selected_ in selection_:
    selected_.data.uv_layers[0]
```

How can I delete certain channel?

I'v got tons of objects with extra uv map in channel 0.
Isn't there something like 
 selected_.data.uv_layers[0].Remove()?...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I *think* this is what you mean, but `data.uv_layers` doesn't provide that functionality. `uv_textures` does. If you hover over the UVMap menu item in UV Maps it's a `uv_texture`.

[image]

```
import bpy

uv_textures = bpy.data.objects['Suzanne'].data.uv_textures
uv_textures.remove(uv_textures['UVMap'])
# uv_textures.remove(uv_textures['UVMap.001'])
# uv_textures.remove(uv_textures[0])   or by uv index
```

You might want something like this:

```
import bpy  

selection = bpy.context.selected_objects

for obj in selection:
    uv_textures = obj.data.uv_textures
    uv_textures.remove(uv_textures[0])
```

for 2.8_1

```
import bpy
    
objdata = bpy.data.objects['Suzanne']
uv_layers =objdata.data.uv_layers
uv_layers.remove(uv_layers['UVMap'])
```

for 2.8_2

```
import bpy  
    
selection = bpy.context.selected_objects
    
for obj in selection:
    uv_textures = obj.data.uv_layers
    uv_textures.remove(uv_textures[0])
```

Comment: Deleting a UV texture will also remove the corresponding UV layer (under normal circumstances). Note that the objects must not be in edit mode.