# How to efficiently remove a huge number of UV Maps from an object?

Tags: mesh, uv, data-blocks

I currently have a model coming from an external source (Revit Architecture) with lots of objects (+3000). I have tidied the model up somewhat and have reduced object count to under 100 by joining objects. This results in objects that have hundreds of UV maps.

Deleting UV maps one at a time is time consuming and tedious. Is there a way to get rid of all the UV maps on an object with a single command or does this require some clever python scripting?

Comment: you go via python: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36523/how-can-i-delete-uv-layers-with-python

Comment: Thank you! How would you modify the last script (delete by index) to go through the whole list of UV map indexes the mesh has?

Comment: if your UVmaps have consecutive names (UVMap01, UVMap02, etc) you can create a cycle to run through all UVMaps. If not, you have to create a list with the names, then read the names from that list.

Comment: The UV maps are not consecutively named. How would I go around creating a list of the names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as in https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?254004-Accessing-UV-data-in-Python-script

```
import bpy
obj= bpy.context.selected_objects
for ob in obj:
    if ob.type == 'MESH':
        bpy.context.scene.objects.active = ob
        while(len(ob.data.uv_textures)):
            bpy.ops.mesh.uv_texture_remove()
```

Comment: you have to try if it works. Maybe change "texture" with "map" or something... I'm a complete noob in python

Comment: I'd go for the low level approach used by @CoDEmanX in post 13 of that BA thread https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?254004-Accessing-UV-data-in-Python-script&p=2687622&viewfull=1#post2687622