# Extending the limit of UV Maps an object can have

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

A little quick one here, but I seemed to have run into a large problem when UV texturing an object. In the object under the data panel, I've successfully created and used a total of eight UV Maps, all with there own names, (Including the first UV Map before I added others).

However, now that I've went back in to add another, it simply does not respond, it doesn't add one, and doesn't give me an error message or whatnot.
Is there a limit to how many UV Maps can be on one object? Or is there a button I can switch to allow me more UV Maps?

I've seen from another question here that someone once had hundreds of UV Maps on single objects, so I don't think its a limitation, but I don't know what's really causing this.

EDIT: I tried to add the UV Maps in the Python console, and the same limitation happens, but this time I get a message when I reach the eighth map.
[image]

It says "cancelled" if I input another command to add in another UV Map. Is there a way to fix that so I can add more?

EDIT:
I tried out creating two objects with the "maximum" amount of UV Maps and combined them, but it did not create any new ones.

I also read [here](https://community.secondlife.com/forums/topic/348429-multiple-uv-maps-for-one-mesh-object/) that there was a maximum of eight available texture spaces. However, that was from two years ago, and I don't know if it's been updated...

I'm using blender internal by the way if you didn't know.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is there anyone that can help me with this? There doesn't seem to be anything on here that asks this question...

Comment: It isn't mentioned in the manual but as far as I know you can't add more than 8, you'll need to create a workaround, like more materials, different objects etc

Comment: About the materials, in my scene I have on object with a multitude of different materials, and in each material there is one separate texture for the image and UV Map. Is that what you are talking about or is it something different?

Comment: I guess something like that, materials which are added in the Properties editor > Materials tab (as one way) and are assigned to different faces / areas of the mesh somehow. It could be interesting to look at the question here you mentioned where more than 8 UV maps are created.

Comment: This is the question I was referring to: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65996/how-to-efficiently-remove-a-huge-number-of-uv-maps-from-an-object

Comment: My issue is that I have one base uv map that every material uses, and then each material uses another uv map atop of that. However, each additional UV Map can not match the unwrap of the base map. I'm gonna ask another question detailing a possible work-around. Hopefully it gets fixed, since I can't move on in my project without this.