# Working around the UV Maps limit

Tags: texturing, uv, workflow, uv-image-editor

Since the maximum amount of UV Maps is eight per object, (I'm not quite sure why),  a workaround is most likely my only option. For this problem, I have a single object that has 55 materials.

There is a base texture that is used in every material and is unwrapped properly. 
[image]

However, every texture *also* has another decal texture specific to that set of faces/wall
[image]

So you see, the base texture is unwrapped differently from the decal, (which is made to fit the proportions of that wall). The way to achieve this effect without messing with both UV unwraps is by UV Maps in the data tab.

However, since there are only eight available on any one object at a time, I can't add anymore to continue the workflow I've done so far.

A possible workaround would be to separate the object into many objects that each have a set number of the UV Maps.
However, is there any other ways I can achieve this effect?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is this a question or an answer to the question you posted here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/88767/extending-the-limit-of-uv-maps-an-object-can-have ?

Comment: Weird, I thought I added the last line, but I had to refresh the page because it thought I had less than ten reputation. Sorry for the mishap, It's a question, but the actual question at the bottom didn't get saved after I came back to it.